# function startWatch on Accelerometer doesnt's works

Tags: javascript, android, html, intel-xdk

Today I came across an error in startwatch role, yesterday was working perfectly, but now does not work properly. Already retired and returned to put the accelerometer plugin, but remains the same. I did not change anything! already been checking the braces and semicolons and everything was correct. Someone can help me with this little error.

Programming in js:

```
      // The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
// variáveis Globais
var watchID = null;
var seg;
var crono;
var nabs;
var movini,movfinal, posinicial,margem;
var posfinal;
var cronometro;
var segundos;


function btnClickStart() {


         $('#btn').hide();
    // 10 segundos para se preparar
        $('#preparar').modal('show');
        var timer = 10;
        var intervalo = setInterval(contagem,1000);
        // função contagem 10 segundos
        function contagem(){
            timer = timer -1;
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=timer;
            if (timer == 0 ){
                clearInterval(intervalo);
                startWatch();
                crono = setInterval(function () {temporizador()}, 1000);
                cronometro = setInterval(function () {temporizador1()}, 1000);
                $('#preparar').modal('hide');
               navigator.vibrate(1500);


            }
        };





    // fazer reset ao crono ' temporaizador
    nabs= 0;
    seg = 0;
    segundos = 10;
    posinicial = 0;
    margem = 0.75;
    posfinal = 7;
    movfinal = false;
    movini = false;
}



function temporizador()
{
   seg = seg + 1;

}  



function temporizador1()
{
   segundos = segundos - 1;

       if(segundos == 0){

            stopWatch();

            function Confirma(buttonIndex) {

                    // Reiniciar
                    if (buttonIndex == 1){

                        btnClickStart();    
                    }
                    // Back
                    if (buttonIndex == 2){
                        history.back();
                    }   

                }

            navigator.notification.confirm(
                    'Fizeste ' + nabs + ' Repetições num Minuto!', // message
                     Confirma,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                    'Parabéns',           // title
                    ['Reiniciar','Voltar Atrás']     // buttonLabels
                );

            navigator.vibrate(500);
       }    
}

// Start watching the acceleration
//
function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 1  miliseconds
    var options = { frequency: 100 };


    //The error is here
    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);



}

// Stop watching the acceleration
//
function stopWatch() {
    clearInterval(crono);
    clearInterval(cronometro);
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
//
function onSuccess(acceleration) {


    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br>' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br>' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br><hr>' +
                        'Tempo: ' + seg.toString()                  + '<br>' +
                        'Cronometro: ' + segundos.toString()        + '<br><hr>' +
                        'Número de ABS: <b>' + nabs.toString()      + '</b><br><hr>' +
                        'Posição Inicial: ' + posinicial.toString() + '<br>' +
                        'Mov Inicial: ' + movini.toString()         + '<br>' +
                        'Mov Final: ' + movfinal.toString()         + '<br>' +
                        'Timestamp: ' + acceleration.timestamp      + '<br>';

    // posição inicial da pessoa
    if (seg == 0) {
        posinicial = acceleration.x;
        movini = true;
        movfinal = false;
    }


    //analisar o movimento
    if (acceleration.x >= posinicial && movini == true && movfinal == false) {
        // detecta se chega à posição em cima
        if((acceleration.x >= posfinal - margem && acceleration.x <= posfinal + margem)){
            movfinal = true;
            movini = false;
            navigator.vibrate(200);

        }
    }
    // inverso
    if ((acceleration.x >= posinicial - margem && acceleration.x <= posinicial + margem) && movfinal == true && movini == false) {

       movini = true;
       movfinal = false;
       nabs = nabs +1;


    }


}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration

function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

I appreciate the Help.

Comment: What is the device you're running on? I've been having troubles with the accelerometer plugin on Android 5 and 6 devices. The problems used to be limited to a small number of Android 5 devices, but seems to have gotten worse. Not sure what happened. I'm rewriting my sample (as time permits) to also use the HTML5 motion/orientation APIs to see if that gives better results.

Comment: My device is vodafone smart speed 6. But the first schedule that was used works perfectly. I tried to create a new project, with the same schedule but did not work properly.

Comment: Try testing with the "Hello, Cordova" sample app, it is very useful for debugging accelerometer and geo issues.

Comment: I have already use that but doesnt works